# Using regex to extract substrings enclosed in certain characters

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex to capture all substrings in form of `++`+text+`--` in a given input. So an example input could be:

```
Some text ++ not interesting text ++interesting part1-- and again some more text ++interesting part2-- and more text and ...
```

which I'd like to extract `++interesting part1--` and `++interesting part2--`.

**My regex attempts**

1. Obviously `++.*?--` does not work. Because for input above it matches "++ not interesting text ++interesting part1--" which is wrong.
2. My other broken solution was the following regex `++(?!.*++).*--` which only captures the second instance ("interesting part2").

Any explanation and answer is welcome.

---

Note: I do want to solve the issue with regex to master it, though I know the problem has easier solution by just looking for `++` and `--` indices repeatedly.

Comment: `\+\+(?:(?!\+\+).)*?--`, https://regex101.com/r/qRWHkD/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the brilliant part of this solution is the `(<negative-lookahead>.)*`. But it's not clear to me how negative-lookahead works in a repetition part. What if we swap `negative-lookahead` and `.`, it seems to work, right?

Comment: See [Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, your comment really helped me and I agree with you upon the duplicate flag. However I can't understand why you downvoted. of course I searched for similar questions before posting mine, but finding other questions is not straight-forward.